# Why the array is created with only the last object from the loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, array-push

I'm trying to create an Array which will be consisting of objects. The most is done, finally, the array has the same number of items but all of them are my last loop object. It seems like some kind of reference. I really don't know where is the problem.

CodePen HTML:

```
<table class="table table-admin-panel table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Active</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-admin-panel-active"><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td> <input class="name" type="text" value="Example 1"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="10"></td>
      <td class="table-admin-panel-remove"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-admin-panel-active"><input type="checkbox" checked=""></td>
      <td> <input class="name" type="text" value="Example 2"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="20"></td>
      <td class="table-admin-panel-remove"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-admin-panel-active"><input type="checkbox" checked=""></td>
      <td> <input class="name" type="text" value="Example 3"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="30"></td>
      <td class="table-admin-panel-remove"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-admin-panel-active"><input type="checkbox" checked=""></td>
      <td> <input class="name" type="text" value="Example 4"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="40"></td>
      <td class="table-admin-panel-remove"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="btn-bps btn-save">Zapisz</button>
</div>
```

CodePen JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-save").click(function(event) {
    var element = new Object();
    var output = new Array();
    $(this).parent(".buttons").siblings("table").find("tr").each(function(index, el) {
        $(this).find("td input").each(function(index2, el) {
          if (index !== 0) {
            if (index2 === 0) {
              var checkboxStatus = $(this).prop("checked");
              if (checkboxStatus === true) {
                element["active"] = "1";
              } else {
                element["active"] = "0";
              }
            } else if (index2 === 1) {
              element["name"] = $(this).val();
            } else if (index2 === 2) {
              element["value"] = $(this).val();
            }
            element["id"] = index - 1 + "";
          }
        });
        output[index] = element;
      });
      console.log(output);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare element inside of the first loop.  Right now you are overwriting the value of the element object with each iteration.  See the code below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-save").click(function(event) {        
    var output = new Array();
    $(this).parent(".buttons").siblings("table").find("tr").each(function(index, el) {
        var element = new Object(); //NEW ELEMENT LOCATION
        $(this).find("td input").each(function(index2, el) {
          if (index !== 0) {
            if (index2 === 0) {
              var checkboxStatus = $(this).prop("checked");
              if (checkboxStatus === true) {
                element["active"] = "1";
              } else {
                element["active"] = "0";
              }
            } else if (index2 === 1) {
              element["name"] = $(this).val();
            } else if (index2 === 2) {
              element["value"] = $(this).val();
            }
            element["id"] = index - 1 + "";
          }
        });
        output[index] = element;
      });
      console.log(output);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for resolving my problem. Why now is it another object if it has the same name `element`?

Comment: It's all about scope.  The element scope you originally had was outside of the loops so when you access element, you are referencing just one instance of the object. When you move it into the first loop, it creates a new instance of the object for each row.

Answer (score 0):

`element` is defined and instantiated once outside the loops (`.each`) and keeping the same reference on each iteration.

Try instantiating it inside the loop.